# Why is a new line NOT starting after a flexbox is completed?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm learning how to utilize `flex` and just started running into issues for **after** the `flexbox` is completed...

```css
#initial {
    display: flex;
    flex: 1;
    justify-content: space-evenly;
    align-items: center;
    width: 1200px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    border: 1px solid white;
}

  #initial .menu {
      display: flex;
      flex: 1;
      justify-content: space-evenly;
      align-items: center;
      margin: 15px auto 15px auto;
      width: 1100px;
      border: 1px solid rgba(245, 245, 245, 0.699);
      border-radius: 50px;
      line-height: 2rem;
      font-size: 1.1rem;
      overflow: hidden;
  }

    #initial .menu .menuItem {
        display: flex;
        flex: 1;
        padding-top: 10px;
        padding-bottom: 10px;
        width: 100%;
        text-align: center;
        flex-direction: column;
        flex-wrap: wrap;
        align-content: space-around;
        justify-content: space-evenly;
    }

    #initial .menu .menuItem:hover {
        background-color: #FDB000;
        color: black;
        cursor: pointer;
        display: flex;
        flex: 1;
        text-align: center;
        flex-direction: column;
        flex-wrap: wrap;
        align-content: space-around;
        justify-content: space-evenly;
    }
```

```html
<div id="initial">
    <div class="menu">
        <div id="initialMenuHeader" class="menuItem" onclick="menuCollapsable(this)">&Delta;</div>
        <div id="initialMenuHVQ" class="menuItem" onclick="initialHVQ()">Hivecoin</div>
        <div id="initialMenuRVN" class="menuItem" onclick="initialRVN()">Ravencoin</div>
        <div id="initialMenuAVN" class="menuItem" onclick="initialAVN()">Avian</div>
    </div>
    <div class="body">
        <h1>NAME OF POOL GOES HERE</h1>
        <p class="intro">¡Intro crap will go here!</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

As it stands, my `.menu` looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wgCsW.jpg). **Please note that the image is uncensored and includes expletives**

Everything I could find online suggests that when the `flex-box` is completed, it should go back to the normal flow (e.g. not floating).

Please let me know what I'm doing wrong and/or missing.

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/yorzjcuv/) of my code (added some things that I didn't include above like `body` for `background-color` and `color`

Comment: Why do you have the shorthand `flex: 1;` in every rule? That looks like cargo-cult programming to me, especially as you're using the longhand versions of all the other flex rules. And why are you altering layout properties in the `:hover` rule? Generally speaking, only color/background/effects properties should be altered in `:hover` rules.

Comment: @Dai it was originally that way because they all showed `display:block` on the dev tools `F12` and I was trying to figure out why - I just haven't gone in and cleaned it up yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you make `#initial` as flex, and by default flex-direction set to `row` your menu align with with your body. If your want menu & body in 2 lines add below css:

```
#initial{
   flex-direction: column;
}
```

Comment: Worked great. Just had to add the column to "Body" as well, which wasn't in my original question, so I didn't expect you to state it. Thank you for your help!